# What's the proper way of setting the salt for cookies in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, cookies, kohana, kohana-3, salt

I could just dive into the Kohana_Cookie class and set

```
public static $salt = 'blah';
```

But this doesn't seem like a very elegant solution... is there a propper way to set it in a config or such? Tried Googling around, but no luck...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either set it in bootstrap:

```
Cookie::$salt = 'foobar';
```

Or extend the cookie class like @davgothic says.

Don't modify code in your system folder. There's never a need to do that.

Comment: Now I'm at a loss at a loss as to which of these mothods to use... haha... Thank you though... I gave the other guy the answer since he was first, but I wouldn't mind if someone chimed in if this is the more standard method of doing this... wouldn't want to send other noobs down the wrong path...   Should I flip to make this the answer folks or leave as is...?

Comment: Well Jeremy (@zombor) is one of the developers on the Kohana team and he makes a very good point, you should never edit any of the Kohana system files. Not when you can extend them as in my answer. My preferred method in this situation is to extend the class. However as Jeremy said it can also be resolved by editing the bootstrap.php if desired.

Comment: Both ways are equally good. Just don't edit your system files. Extend the class in your application folder. It's "easier" to just set it in your bootstrap because you don't have to do the class inheritance, but they are both fine.

Comment: I ended up putting the one-liner just before the return() in config/session.php which is the module which required the salted cookie anyway. Seems cleaner.

Comment: @vee write it after I18n::lang

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by creating a `cookie.php` file in `application/classes` with the following contents:

```
class Cookie extends Kohana_Cookie
{
    public static $salt = 'foobar';
} // End Cookie
```

I would advise going with zombor's approach below though.

Comment: "Most people" don't do this. You need to set it in the bootstrap.